# Burninate request: checker

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

[checker](/questions/tagged/checker) has been used for all kinds of things:

- Checkerboards
- Sudoku validation
- Finding URLs
- Checking syntax
- Validating a specific format
- Finding the encoding of a string

And much more. A question being tagged [checker](/questions/tagged/checker) tells you nothing, as it could still be about pretty much anything using pretty much any technology. Is there any worth to this tag?

Comment: Off-the-cuff, I see about nine questions that might be worth saving.  As for the tag itself...not really.  Its misuse makes its true intention ambiguous, and to be frank, I don't see any value in having the tag around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've burned this tag, and voted to close all but 3 (of 31) questions.

*Assuming no funny business it'll be gone by tomorrow.*